# My application quicklist goes missing when using "quickly submitubuntu"

Tags: application-development, quickly, quicklists

I'm trying to submit my app for the app showdown, but I've just noticed that when I use the "submitubuntu" Quickly command, my dynamic quicklist entries don't work. I think this is because the desktop file gets renamed from tickit.desktop to extras-tickit.desktop

I'm coding a hacky fix to look for /usr/share/applications/extras-tickit.desktop and changing the argument for get_for_desktop_id() if it exists, but is there a better way? Can I stop Quickly renaming the desktop file?

Answer (score 0):

The [App Review Board Guidelines](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppReviewBoard/Review/Guidelines) say in the section "Packaging":

> The .desktop file is installed in the standard location /usr/share/applications, but  must have the prefix 'extras-' added to its name. Example: extras-foobar.desktop for a package named foobar.

So Quickly is doing The Right Thing here and you should rename your .desktop file.